# google structured data price not showing in google

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have configured a google structured data for a product. Although each itemprop was showing up in google tools with no errors.  example:  [Google structured data tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wagner-group.com%2Fde%2Fheimwerker%2Fprodukte-zubehoer%2Fprodukt%2Fairless-sprayer-control-pro-250-m%2F). But in google i couldn't see the price. Same link in google  [Same link in google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=Hr-sXbu-A8qMa8n3k8gB&q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wagner-group.com%2Fde%2Fheimwerker%2Fprodukte-zubehoer%2Fprodukt%2Fairless-sprayer-control-pro-250-m%2F&oq=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wagner-group.com%2Fde%2Fheimwerker%2Fprodukte-zubehoer%2Fprodukt%2Fairless-sprayer-control-pro-250-m%2F&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7143.7143..7430...0.0..0.0.0.......0....2j1..gws-wiz.&ved=0ahUKEwi7xeG50qvlAhVKxhoKHcn7BBkQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) . I have followed the google documentation. For the price for example i coded like this (Just i putt static values for simplicity) :

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscopeitemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
 <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">€</span>
 <span itemprop="price" content="6599.59">6.599,59</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the price here for your supplied search. However not when I try a more natural search, and not for all your product pages.

It can take time for Google to crawl and process a pages. Updates may take more time to propagate around all their servers.

Rich snippets are not guaranteed even if the markup is valid. Artificial searches like ones using site: are more likely to show rich snippets than real world searches.

Comment: thanks, yes i'm seeing the price now. Maybe it takes time.